# CoreData mark one record as favourite (mutually exclusive)

Tags: ios, swift, database, sqlite, core-data

## Overview:

- I have an `iOS` app that uses `CoreData`
- There is an entity called `Animal`
- It has a set of records `Lion`, `Tiger` and `Elephant`
- I would like to mark **only one** of the records as favourite.

#### Similar entities with the same approach:

- Similarly I could have other entities such as `Car`, `Bike`.
- Each entity would have a set of records.
- Again each entity should only have one favourite record

#### Reason:

- App has an option to create a new document
- When the new document is created, it would be populated with default values for each entity (by selecting the favourite record of each entity)

**Note**: Only one record can be marked as favourite at a given time

## Possible models I thought of:

#### 1. Field called isFavourite

- Create a field in `Animal` called `isFavourite`.
- Mark only one of the rows as `isFavourite` as `true`.
- Much of the logic to maintain isFavourite is managed in code.

#### 2. Separate entity called Favourite

- Create a separate table called `Favourite` and have a dummy row in it.
- Establish a relationship from `Favourite` to `Animal` called `animal`.
- This will point to the favourite record.

## Questions:

1. What is the preferred approach to tackle this problem ?
2. Are there any other alternatives ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go with option 2, maybe call it Config. If you want to ensure it is just a singleton add a attribute that is unique and can only be zero.

You can write a helper computed var returning true if the reverse relationship is non-nil.

Main advantage of option 2 is the simplicity of changing the favourite, you don't have to scan through all the items to to set them non-favourite just change it on the singleton config.

Comment: Setting unique and check constraints certainly helps. And renaming it as `Config` adds so much more clarity to the purpose. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Give some thought to other parts of the app and to what you might want to do in the future.

Adding a field: Works OK but requires some code to maintain, which might be error prone. On the other hand maybe one day the app might allow multiple favorites, and this will just work with that.

Using a separate entity: Also works OK but adds a whole new entity where you'll only have a single instance. In general, if you have an entity where you only ever want one instance, you're doing it wrong. On the other hand this also works well with the potential for multiple favorites.

A third approach is to save the `objectID` for the favorite animal somewhere outside of Core Data, like `UserDefaults`. Save it, and then find the favorite by using `NSManagedObjectContext`'s `existingObject(with:)` method. You can't save the `NSManagedObjectID` directly but you can get its `uriRepresentation()` and save that.

I'd probably go with #1 in most cases but it depends what else I need in the app.

Comment: I might in the future have more entities like `Car` `Bike` which have some data in it. Each entity would need to have a separate favourite. Again the favourite needs to be only record. Reason for all this is when user creates a new document it would be populated with these default values (selected from the favourite record for each entity).